# Simplicity of rotational symmetry group of dodecahedron without proving it is $A_5$

Tags: geometry, finite-groups

I am trying to prove that the rotational symmetry group $G$ of a regular dodecahedron is $A_5$.

I am trying to do this in an unusual way: I want to show that $G$ is simple. Since I can show $G$ is order 60 and can prove that any simple group of order 60 is $A_5$  I just need to argue it is simple.

I am aware of the standard proof that $G$ is $A_5$ by embedding cubes/ tetrahedrons: I want to prove that $G$ is simple without first showing it is $A_5$

Comment: Well, then pick the subgroups one by one and show they aren't normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a combinatorial way, by simply counting elements and using the regularity of your dodecahedron. In the isometry group, you have

- the identity element
- $6\times 4=24$ elements of order $5$ (rotations with axe face-face),
- $15\times 1=15$ elements of order $2$ (rotations with axe edge-edge),
- $10\times 2=20$ elements of order $3$ (rotations with axe vertex-vertex).

Remark furthermore that by regularity of the dodecahedron, you act transitively on the set of axes face-face, on the set of axes edge-edge and the set of axes vertex-vertex. Since the rotations associated to each axe are of prime order, **if a normal subgroup contain one rotation of given order, it contains all rotations of this order.**

As a result we only have the following possibility (identity + some conjugacy classes) for the order of the normal subgroup:

$$1\text{, }16\text{, }21\text{, }25\text{, }36\text{, }40\text{, }45\text{, }60\text{.}$$

and using Lagrange's theorem the only possibility are $1$ and $60$.

Comment: Thank you, with the bit in bold I am able to convince myself that this is true through Sylow (for 3 and 5) and geometrical reasoning for 2. The way you phrased it made me suspect there is a general result about subgroups of prime order you are appealing to?

Comment: @Patrick, my point is to **not** use Sylow theorem here. Let me expand a bit. Suppose I have a rotation $c$ of order $p$ in my normal subgroup  and $d$ a rotation with the same order $p$. Then, by transitivity of the action on the axes I get  that $c$ is conjugated to $d^k$ and since the order of $d$ is prime, $\langle d^k\rangle$ must contain $d$. Thus $d$ is contained in my normal subgroup as well.